# no puedo escribir el slash invertido en pycharm

Tags: pycharm

He cambiado el idioma a inglés para poder escribir el slash invertido y he probado en word o en el buscador y se escribe correctamente pero cuando uso  la misma tecla en pycharm me sale este otro símbolo (¥), también he usado el teclado en español usando alt+92 que corresponde al slash invertido y ha resultado lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer, este es un problema conocido y reportado en la comunidad de **Jetbrains** que debería solucionarse actualizando a la versión de **PyCharm 2020.3.3** o superior.

- [Unable to enter backslash](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010239340-Unable-to-enter-backslash)
- [Cannot enter \ character on qwertz keyboard layout on macos](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258227?_ga=2.200893416.714622486.1649390103-1713167896.1641530193#focus=Comments-27-4620777.0-0)

No obstante, hay una [solución](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258227#focus=Comments-27-4620777.0-0) para las versiones que presentan el bug:

1. Abre la ventana de `Settings` en `File` > `Settings` o bien, si tienes el `keymap` estándar, usando `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `S`
2. Selecciona `Keymap` en el menú lateral.
3. Selecciona `Main Menu` en la lista desplegable, y despliega las opciones.
4. Selecciona `Code` > `Code Completion`
5. Haz click derecho en `Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)` y selecciona remover.
6. Selecciona `Apply`.

Eso debería resolver el bug. Me haces saber si te funcionó.

Comment: Tus instrucciones fueron super claras y el problema lo resolvi sin problema, muchismas gracias!